# "ng build --prod" remove code line, if i use console.log(object), not remove

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular8

When I package my Angular 8 project with the command `ng build --prod`, I have this problem.
The following line of code says, `gisModule.Map = args [0];` After compiling does not fall into the code, almost deleted. And my application gives error in the following stages. But when I write `console.log (gisModule.Map)` after this line of code, everything works fine. What would be the reason? Is there a more effective solution?

The first version of the code,

```
import { gisModule } from 'gisModule';
...
...
loadModules(["esri/map"]).then(function (args: any) {

    gisModule.Map = args[0];

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
})
```

after the code is compiled,

```
ze.then(() => {
    Object(o.loadModules)(["esri/map"]).then(function (e) {
        He().bootstrapModuleFactory(Be).catch(e => console.error(e))
    })
}
```

Only console.log added,

```
loadModules(["esri/map"]).then(function (args: any) {
    gisModule.Map = args[0];
    //Just adding this line,is work well.
    console.log(gisModule.Map);
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
})
```

After add console.log Output is,

```
Ue.then(() => {
Object(i.loadModules)(["esri/map"]).then(function (e) {
        s.Map = e[0],
        console.log(s.Map),
        Fe().bootstrapModuleFactory(ze).catch(e => console.error(e))
 })
}
```

And My gisModule.ts is here

```
export class gisModule{ 
    static set Map(value: any) {
        _my_global_variable = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should report this as a bug, there's not much SO can do to help you with it.

Comment: my assumption is that the treeshaking being executed during the compilation detects your gisModule as never used, so deleted. But adding the console.log line, it's used and not deleted. In exmaples found online, it seems that esri/map is loaded in components rather than into main.ts

Comment: As you said, something directly from gisModule is not used. "gisModule.map" is an accessor. And the content is like this `static set Map (value: any) {
        _my_global_variable = value;
    } `  Thank you now I get it. @GérômeGrignon